# How do I configure the PHP Zend Framework in Netbeans?

Tags: 10.10, netbeans, zend

Anyone installed zend-framework plugin? I installed it, but cannot create any php-zend-framework projects. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

In this project I am not able to check the checkbox (neither zend nor symfony). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution here:

http://linux-open-free.blogspot.com/2010/11/ubuntu-1010-can-not-select-framework-on.html

Comment: This answer is not very good. It only provides a link which does not even answer the question.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure you have the Plugin installed, ubuntu Netbeans installation is a vanilla one pretty much, you gotta add your plugins manually. once you do so, go to `Tools -> Options -> PHP -> Zend and configure it`. Then, start a new project :)

The plugin is called "PHP Zend Framework"

Comment: i ve installed plugin but and i get the option in the php frameworks option but why don't i get to check it? (i mean it is disabled)

Comment: could you please explain me what does this 'vanilla one' mean? I would really appreciate

Comment: Sorry for not answering, been pretty busy. Ok, a vanilla installation is one that have only the necessary plug-ins to run and the default settings, you have to configure it properly. There is nothing added to it or modified. yOU might want to ask in netbeans mailing list, I ran out of ideas for that one :(. The weirdest thing is that I've the same netbeans as you (from ubuntu repositories) and it just works for me...